# How does man work in linux?

Tags: linux, man

When we `man std::vector`,how/where does it search for corresponding documents internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `man(1)` man page:

> ```
> SEARCH PATH FOR MANUAL PAGES
>    man uses a sophisticated method of finding manual page files, based  on
>    the  invocation  options and environment variables, the /etc/man.config
>    configuration file, and some built in conventions and heuristics.
>
>    First of all, when the name argument to man contains a slash  (/),  man
>    assumes  it  is  a file specification itself, and there is no searching
>    involved.
>
>    But in the normal case where name doesn’t contain a slash, man searches
>    a variety of directories for a file that could be a manual page for the
>    topic named.
> ```

There's a lot more text in there though. I'll let you read it at your leisure.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,can you guide me how to install the libc++ docs manually ? ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/libstdc++/doxygen/libstdc++-api.20100719.man.tar.bz2

Comment: `yum install  libstdc++-docs` this doesn't work for me(`No package libstdc++-docs available.`),so I assume that c++ man docs aren't available in my repository:(

Comment: Copy all the `.<n>` files to the `man<n>/` directories, usually in `/usr/share/man`.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,files under `/usr/share/man/man` are all zipped,i.e. `ldap_abandon_ext.3.gz`,but the docs I downloaded are only tared,not zipped. And I tried to unzip it,still fails... Can you be more specific on the steps?

Comment: Extract the files from the archive. Move or copy them. It doesn't matter that the individual man pages aren't compressed; `man` doesn't care.

Comment: Would you mind un-nesting your `BLOCKQUOTE`? It looks wrong as it is. (I would but the editor flags it as "not substantial enough".

Comment: @new123456: Unfortunately this is a side effect of using monospace quoting with this CSS; it looks wrong, but is actually correct.